# Bitbucket pipelines/Docker : Connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to configure a bitbucket CI pipeline to run tests.Stripping out the details I have a make file which looks as follows to run some form of integration tests.

```
test-e2e:
docker-compose -f ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE} up -d ${APP_NAME} 
godog
docker-compose -f ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE} down
```

Docker compose is a single webserver with ports exposed.

Pipeline looks as follows:

```
     - step: &integration-testing 
    name: Run integration tests script: # do this to make go module work with private repo 
    - apk add libc-dev py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make bash 
    - pip install docker-compose - git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/" 
    - go get github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo 
    - go get github.com/onsi/gomega/... 
    - go get github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/cmd/godog 
    - make build-only && make test-e2e
```

I am facing two separate issues for both i have not been able to find a solution.

1. Keep getting connection refused when the tests are run.

To elaborate above, the docker compose brings up a server with proper host:port mapping ("127.0.0.1:10077:10077"). The command godog is intended to run the tests by querying the server. This however always ends in connection refused.[This link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Pipeline-docker-exec-curl-7-Failed-to-connect-Connection-refused/qaq-p/708236)  has a possible solution , so i am exploring that.

2. The pipeline almost always runs commands before the container is up. I've tried fixing this by changing the invoke to.

   ```
    test-e2e:
     docker-compose -f ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE} up -d ${APP_NAME} && sleep 10 && docker exec -i oracle-go godog && docker-compose -f ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE} down
   ```

However the container is always brought up after the sleep (almost instantaneously).

```
Example:

Creating oracle-go ... 
Sleep 10
docker ps CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
docker exec -i oracle-go godog
Creating oracle-go ... done
Error response from daemon: Container 7bab5322203756b972e7f0a3c6e5827413279914a68c705221b8af7daadc1149 is not running
```

Please let me know if there is a way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to wait for the server to start before running tests.

Instead of manually `sleep`ing, you should use [`wait-for-it.sh`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) (or an alternative). See the relevant [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more information.

For example:

```
test-e2e:
  bash wait-for-it.sh <HOST>:<PORT> -- docker-compose -f ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE} up -d ${APP_NAME} && docker exec -i oracle-go godog && docker-compose -f ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE} down
```

Change `<HOST>` and `<PORT>` to your service's host name and port respectively. Alternatively, you could use `wait-for-it.sh` in your Docker Compose `command` or the like.